# Chimeric Gene vs Fusion Gene?

Tags: terminology, mutations, gene

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimeric_gene) on chimeric genes:

> These mutations are distinct from fusion genes which merge whole gene
>   sequences into a single reading frame and often retain their original
>   functions.

I am not totally sure I understand the statement. My interpretation is that a fusion gene is caused by a translocation of DNA in a single gene; therefore, it "retains their original functions". This is different from a chimeric gene where DNA from two or more different genes are translocated to a new location to form a completely new gene.

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chimeric gene is formed from fragments of other genes whereas a fusion gene is formed from the entirety of other genes. Often in the literature you'll see the term fusion gene used for both cases.